# After deleting desktop file, where is the input focus?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop, input, focus

Bit of a random question...

On my Windows 10 computer, I deleted a file from the desktop. I realised I'd deleted the wrong file, so I immediately hit Ctrl+Z which I know Windows supports for undoing actions in Explorer. However, nothing happened. I right-clicked on the desktop, and selected Undo from the context menu, and the file returned as expected.

It seems that after I deleted the file, the focus was no longer on the desktop. I tried again - deleting a file, and immediately using the up/down/left/right keys, and hitting spacebar. Nothing seems to happen. I'm curious - where *is* the focus at this point in time? Are my keystrokes being sent anywhere, maybe without me realising?

Comment: Should be on the the desktop with no item focused. So hitting left arrow will move the focus from the background to the second from left top icon and also select it.